# PDF styles not properly rendering using ASPOSE Library

Tags: java, aspose, aspose-cells, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

We are using ASPOSE for content download in Word & PDF format. We don’t have separate code format for PDF or WORD.

There is only one base code format to retrieve data from database,finally will add the response type based on PDF(SaveFormat.PDF) or WORD (SaveFormat.DOCX).

When we change running head styles we get the correct format in WORD as expected but not in PDF.

Note : We do have updated ASPOSE JAR still its not working.

Could you please help on this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.sam.test;



import java.text.MessageFormat;

import com.aspose.words.Document;
import com.aspose.words.DocumentBuilder;
import com.aspose.words.HeaderFooterType;
import com.aspose.words.ParagraphAlignment;
import com.aspose.words.SaveFormat;

public class SuperScriptTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String fontName = "Times New Roman";
        String fontColour = "black";
        Double fontSize = 15.9996;
        Double lineheight = 100.0;
        String footerVariable = "";

        Document doc = new Document();
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
        builder.writeln("Aspose Sample document Content for Word &#1; file.");


        com.aspose.words.Section currentSection = builder.getCurrentSection();
        com.aspose.words.PageSetup pageSetup = currentSection.getPageSetup();
        pageSetup.setDifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter(true);
        // --- Create header for the first page. ---
        pageSetup.setHeaderDistance(0.5 * 72 );
        pageSetup.setFooterDistance(0.5 * 72);
        builder.moveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HEADER_FIRST);
        builder.getParagraphFormat().setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

        String runningHead = "Running Head Test";
        runningHead = MessageFormat
                .format("<span style=\"margin:0px; font-family:{0}; font-size:{1}px; color:{2}; line-height:{3}%;\">{4}</span>",
                        fontName, fontSize, fontColour, lineheight,
                        runningHead);
        if (!doc.getLastSection().getBody().hasChildNodes())
            doc.getLastSection().remove();
        builder.insertHtml(runningHead);

        doc.save("C:/ASPOSE/Examples/ASPOSEPOC1/Aspose_word_doc.docx",SaveFormat.DOCX);
        doc.save("C:/ASPOSE/Examples/ASPOSEPOC1/Aspose_pdf_doc.pdf",SaveFormat.PDF);

    }

}
```

Comment: I tested your scenario with the latest (20.3.0) version of Aspose.Words for Java and do not see any problems with the generated PDF document. Also I converted the generated DOCX document to PDF using MS Word and compared PDFs produced by Aspose.Words and MS Word - the PDFs look the same. I would suggest you to post the question in the Aspose.Words support forum and attach your documents for investigation.

Comment: @AlexeyNoskov Thanks for helping me. 

The issue in running head height varying in PDF. If you are taking print out to will see clearly. Word format is too good but not in PDF.

Comment: Unfortunately I still do not see any significant difference. There is a barely visible pixel difference in text on my side. Please report the problem in Aspose.Words forum https://forum.aspose.com/c/words and attach there your documents.